# Update table column based on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table `Table1` that look something like this:

```
Number     Name    Exist
-------------------------
245435     John
64443      Sam
57133      *NULL*
89373      Jame
```

and another table `Table2`:

```
Number     Name    
----------------
245435     John
64443      Sam
*NULL*     Jame
```

I'm just wondering how to update the Table1's `Exist` column with "**YES**" OR "**NO**", depending on whether either `Table1.Number` or `Table1.Name` or both also exist in `Table2`. So one value need to be found in `Table2`.

I have this so far but not sure how to add YES or NO.

```
UPDATE table1 
SET Exist = (SELECT TOP 1 Number 
             FROM table2 
             WHERE table1.Number = table2.Number 
                OR table1.Name = table2.Name);
```

Comment: You should look for CASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a `CASE` expression

```
UPDATE table1 
SET Exist = (CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                         FROM table2 
                         WHERE table1.Number = table2.Number 
                            OR table1.Name = table2.Name) 
            THEN 'YES' 
            ELSE 'NO' 
         END);
```